# UIPageViewController not showing anything but black screen - but doesn't throw errors

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am developing an application for iOS using swift. 
I have already set up one UIPageViewController successfully in my project, so I know how it works.
But now I'm trying to set up a second PageViewController, and it just doesn't work - it doesn't throw any errors either, it just goes directly to black screen and doesn't even show any segues

What I have tried so far:

1. Resetting the iOS simulator
2. Reindexing the xcode files
3. Restarting xcode
4. Restarting my machine

None of these things have helped.

My code:

(BTW: This code is almost the exactly same as in my working UIPageViewController, the only difference is in the variables' names)

```
import UIKit

class SelectDestinationViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var destinationViewControllers : [UIViewController] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("View did appear")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    let firstView = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstView") as FirstDestinationViewController
    let secondView = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondView") as SecondDestinationViewController

    destinationViewControllers = [firstView, secondView]

    for var index = 0; index < destinationViewControllers.count; ++index {

        println("\(destinationViewControllers[index])")

    }

    let startingViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)
    let viewControllers: NSArray = [startingViewController]

    self.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: {(done: Bool) in})
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    println("View will appear!")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index:NSInteger) -> UIViewController {
    return destinationViewControllers[index]
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var index = find(destinationViewControllers, viewController)!

    if (index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound) {

        return nil

    }

    index--

    if index == destinationViewControllers.count {

        return nil

    }

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var index = find(destinationViewControllers, viewController)!

    if index == NSNotFound {

        return nil

    }

    index++

    if index == destinationViewControllers.count {

        return nil

    }

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

    return destinationViewControllers.count

}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

    return 0

}
```

}

All the prints are showing up in the console - but nothing else is happening.
Does anyone know what the problem might be?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Is this view controller in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes, definetely is :)

Comment: Add a breakpoint after getting the firstView and secondView, check if you are getting the right view controllers and not nil.

Comment: The correct viewcontrollers are indeed loaded in the variables and the "destinationViewControllers" array

Comment: if (index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)  Why are you checking if the index is 0 here?

Comment: The reason I'm checking for index == 0 here is that if I don't, the app will crash :) If I'm at the first page, there wont be any pages before it.
I just moved all the files to a separate project to see if it would work then - it did ... it's very strange

Answer (score -1):

Believe it or not the `UIPageViewController` class is actually not supposed to be viewed by itself. As with the split view controller class (but unlike the tab controller class) you need to have a master view which wraps up the page view controller.

You also need to do some inelegant tricks to get the page view controllers to load without being linked in via the storyboard. When you see code where someone has got it working you can tell they had to know way too much about `UIViewController` internals to get something so simple working..

It would be a bit clearer if, as with the split view controller, it showed you a standard set-up when you put it into your storyboard, but unfortunately the tab view, split view, and page view all behave very differently.

Comment: Can you provide links to the "code where someone has got it working"?